# VSTS API for accessing project queues?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need to programmatically set the queue ID in a VSTS (now Azure DevOps) release definition. I've found this post:

[How to list VSTS agent pools programmatically from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221592/how-to-list-vsts-agent-pools-programmatically-from-powershell)

Unfortunately the APIs in that post are higher level than I need because that deal with agent pools, which are defined at the organization level. I need to get the project-specific queues that reference these agent pools so that I can inject the queue ID into my release definition. Are there APIs to get what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for what I needed and wanted to share with others. There are indeed undocumented APIs to get the project-specific queues. Use a GET request with the following to get the list of queues:

https://foo.visualstudio.com/Project_Name/_apis/distributedtask/queues/

Similarly, if you want the info on a specific queue, GET the following:

https://foo.visualstudio.com/Project_Name/_apis/distributedtask/queues/QUEUEID

**Edit**

I talked with Azure DevOps engineers at MS and they indicated that this is indeed the correct way to get queue info. They also said that, while these APIs are undocumented currently, they are supported (I was referred to this [post](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/285)) and support all RESTful HTTP verbs, although I have not tested this last statement.