# Change agent enabled/disabled status in Azure Devops using REST API

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Apologies ahead of time if this is answered somewhere in an obvious place, I have looked around and couldn't find it.

I can use instructions here ([How to list VSTS agent pools programmatically from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51221592/how-to-list-vsts-agent-pools-programmatically-from-powershell)) to query Azure Devops to get a list of agents, each has an "enabled" field which is either true or false.

In the web interface, this is a check box that the user can select/deselect.  Is there a way to toggle this using the REST API?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is not in Azure DevOps REST Api documentation, but you can change the agent status in this way (it's `PATCH` call):

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents/{agentId}
```

Reqeust body (in Json):

```
{"enabled":{false/true},"id":{agentId},"maxParallelism":1,"name":"{agentName}"}
```

**Update:**

It's documented now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: I think it is still an official API call, just not documented.  There is an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/285#issuecomment-439468208) to get it documented, but probably won't happen for a bit.  The pipeline PM mentioned anything in the _apis/ namespace is a public contract and won't have breaking changes.

Comment: Thank you, in the issue I see only get agents and not how update agent, but I updated my answer :)

Comment: A few things I found:
1. Unless the URI ends with ?api-version=(something) the call will fail
2. Unless the media type is "application/json" the call will fail
3. maxParallelism/name properties aren't required

Comment: Thank you for these comments!

Comment: It's in the documentation now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0